# Tengo problemas para hacer un login usando email o numero de control en laravel y sentinel

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo un login para una escuela y me piden que el maestro se logee con su email pero que los alumnos lo hagan con el numero de control que les asigna la escuela.
Al entrar al login seleccionan por medio de un checkbox si eres maestro o alumno, dependiendo la seleccion te pide o email o # de control.

Estoy  usando laravel y Sentinel de Cartalyst

Este es el formulario

```
<form id="login-form" action="/login" method="post">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Acceso para</label>
                        <div> 
                        <label>
                            <input id="maestro" class="radio squared" name="squared-radios" value="maestro" type="radio">
                            <span>Maestro</span>
                        </label> 
                        <label>
                            <input id="alumno" class="radio squared" name="squared-radios" value="alumno" type="radio">
                            <span>Alumno</span>
                        </label> 
                        </div>
                        <div id="emailLabel" class="form-group"> <label for="email">Email</label> <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control underlined" name="email" id="username" placeholder="email@ejemplo.com"> </div>
                        <div id="no_controlLabel" class="form-group"> <label for="no_control">Numero de Control</label> <input id="no_control" type="text" class="form-control underlined" name="no_control" id="username" placeholder="0123456789"> </div>
                        <div class="form-group"> <label for="password">Contraseña</label> <input type="password" class="form-control underlined" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required> </div>
                        <div class="form-group"> <label for="remember">
        <input class="checkbox" id="remember" type="checkbox"> 
        <span>Recordar</span>
      </label> <a href="reset.html" class="forgot-btn pull-right">Olvidaste la contraseña?</a> </div>
                        <div class="form-group"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Acceder</button> </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <p class="text-muted text-xs-center">Olvide el Numero de Control? <a href="signup.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#n-control-modal">Encuentralo Aqui!</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

este es una modificacion que le hice al archivo EloquentUser.php de Sentinel

```
protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'no_control',
        'password',
        'last_name',
        'first_name',
        'permissions',
    ];
protected $loginNames = ['email','no_control'];
```

Esta es la ruta

```
Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@login');
```

y el controlador LoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Sentinel;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('login');

    }
    public function login(Request $request){
        Sentinel::authenticate($request->all());
        return redirect('/');

    }
    public function logout(){
        Sentinel::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Me redirecciona al login ya que en el controlador del panel tengo esto

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Sentinel;

class PanelController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        if(Sentinel::check()== null){
            return redirect('/login');
        }else{       
            return view('contenidos.panel');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema que muestras es que no se puede conectar a la base de datos, revisa tu configuración en `.env` y en `config/database.php`

Comment: Error mio no iniciar mysql, pero sigue sin logearme solo me redirecciona al login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Di con la solucion solo me costo despegarme un rato del monitor y pensar en otras cosas, el problema era en el loginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Sentinel;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('login');

    }
    public function login(Request $request){
        Sentinel::authenticate($request->all());
        return redirect('/');

    }
    public function logout(){
        Sentinel::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

lo cambie por esto

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Sentinel;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('login');

    }
    public function login(Request $request){
        $datos = $request->all();
        //Sentinel::authenticate($request->all());
        if($datos['email'] == null ){
            $credenciales = [
                'no_control'    => $datos['no_control'],
                'password' => $datos['password'],
            ];
            Sentinel::authenticate($credenciales);
        }else if($datos['no_control'] == null){
             $credenciales = [
                'email'    => $datos['email'],
                'password' => $datos['password'],
            ];
            Sentinel::authenticate($credenciales);
        }

        return redirect('/');

    }
    public function logout(){
        Sentinel::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```